# Semi-automatic classification plugin (SCP) error: local variable 'u' referenced before assignment

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification

I use Ubuntu Xenial operating system. I can't use the *Semi-automatic classification plugin (SCP)* in QGIS. When I use a tool in the complement QGIS it just shuts down and then I need to restart the software. So I reinstall the complement then the software shows me this message from Python:

```
local variable 'u' referenced before assignment
```

Any idea of how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

According to the listed issues in the [Code repository](https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin) this error is a known issue ([Local variable 'u' referenced before assignment - installation issue #13](https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues/13))  fixed by installing version 5.0.5

Comment: I though the same thing but I don't know what is happening, now I try to reinstall QGIS but the repositories bring me this message 404 not found